# Shared or Team owned Dashboards in Offline Mode

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, outlook-2010

I have a dashboard 'my stuff' and a team called 'the best team'. I only want members of 'the best team' to be able to see the dashboard 'my stuff'.

Because I'm a member of the team 'the best team', I can see the dashboard 'my stuff' when I'm in online mode. If I then select to go offline, the dashboard 'my stuff' isn't available any more.

Does anyone know why and is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0):

This may be a long shot but are you sure the dashboard is part of of the offline sync?

Comment: on the system I am working on, if a user creates their own dashboard, it is available in both online and offline mode (so to answer your question, yes I think so). However if the Administrator creates a dashboard and shares it with the team, is only available to the members of the team in online mode...

Comment: I'm only making educated guesses at this but if the problem dashboard is shared with the team and by that users get access via the team, that dashboard may not be part of the offline sync by default. I think you can manage what is synced offline via outlook but as I don't use outlook I'm not sure. Might be worth looking at what is set up to sync.

Comment: As far as I'm aware it is only possible to define filters for entity data which should be synced offline to Outlook - ie. appointments/phonecalls/etc which meet some criteria... I'm unaware of any way to define these offline settings for dashboards...

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, Microsoft REALLY didn't think through the default 'offline filters.'

They set everything to 'MY' as opposed to 'MY and MY TEAM.'

The work around for you is to change your 'offline filters' but sadly, you have to manually adjust this for everyone of your users.